# Where to put inverse="true" in nHibernate mapping file

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

According to nHibernate profiler, I need to add inverse="true" to my mapping file, however, I can't seem to find examples on where exactly to put this property. Can anyone tell me based on the following mapping file where I need to put inverse="true"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   auto-import="true"
                   namespace="LROLib.Domain"
                   assembly="LROLib">
  <class name="TestResult" table ="Test_Results" >
    <id name="Test_Result_Id" >
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Test_Result" class="Result" column="Result_Id" />
    <many-to-one name="Test_Applicant" class="Applicant" column="Applicant_Id"/>

    <property name="Test_Name" />
    <property name="Value" />
    <property name="Hi_Lo_Ind" />
    <property name="Range" />
    <property name="Unit_Of_Measure" />
    <property name="Lo_Range" />
    <property name="Hi_Range" />
    <property name="Create_DateTime" update="false"/>
    <property name="Update_DateTime" />
    <property name="User_Name" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases 'inverse' is to identify the relationship owner. For your particular case this should be in your `Result` and `Applicant` mappings.

You can read more in [this blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/). To quote / paraphrase a particularly relevant statement from that article:

> However the “inverse” keyword itself is not verbose enough, I would suggest change the [`inverse`] keyword to "`relationship_owner`".
>
> In short, `inverse="true"` means this is the relationship owner, and `inverse="false"` (default) means it’s not.

Comment: Thanks mynkow, I realized I was looking in the wrong mapping file. I went to my Applicant mapping file and updated the following section:    <set name="TestResults" order-by="Test_Result_Id asc" inverse="true">
      <key column="Applicant_Id"/>
      <one-to-many class="TestResult"/>
    </set>

Answer (score 1):

When I was a hibernate beginner, I was confused about deciding "inverse=true" or "inverse=false".

Here is an easy way to understanding it:

example scenario:
Person(one) <-> Address(many)
        bi-directional one-to-many relationship. (A person has multiple addresses.)

```html
public class Person {
  private Integer id;
  private Set<Address> addresses;

  // setter, getter
  Set<Address> getAddresses() { return addresses; }
  ....
}
```

```html
public class Address {
  private Integer id;
  private Person person;

  // setter, getter
  Person getPerson() { return person; }
  .....
}
```

- Person class has "Set getAddresses()" method
- Address class has "Person getPerson()" method

If you think about the relation between two classes, it may gives an idea that person has addresses. (Person -> Addresses)
So, it feels like a person is an owner, and an address is a child. Then, you want to think that address is "inverse=true" because address is owned by person.
However, it's not correct.

Here, I'd like to suggest a way to think about it. Let's look at table structure instead of classes.

- PERSON[ id, name, ...]
- ADDRESS[ id, person_id, city, street,...]

The person_id column in Address table is the relational information between thease two tables.
So, Address is an owner of the relationship, and Person is the inverse side.
"inverse=true" means "**this side is the inverse side**", and "inverse=false" means "**this is not the inverse side**. this side is the owner of the relationship".

```html
<class name="Person">
  <id name="id">...</id>
  <set name="addresses" inverse="true">
    <key column="person_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Address"/>
  </set>
</class>


<class name="Address">
  <id name="id">...</id>
  <many-to-one name="person" class="Person" />
</class>
```

In sum, look at the table structure to distinguish "inverse=true" or "inverse=false".
If the table has relational information, then it is the owner side. So, it's not inverse side.(inverse=false)
If the table doesn't have relational information, then it is the inverse side. So, it needs "inverse=true".

Answer (score 0):

You can find a well explained tutorial in: [What is “inverse”](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/)  by mkyong.

It focuses on what @mynkow states and give you some examples for inserting and updating regarding the value of **inverse** attribute.

If I were you, I would give it a look.